# CRM 2011 Async Post Update Plugin

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I have an Aynchronous Post-Operation plugin runs on an Update step. Now my challange is to find original values for the fields that the user is updating. Since it is post-operation step, is it possible to find the previous value fields that were updated?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Register a `preimage` snapshot of your entity against the step in your plugin.

[Pre and Post Entity Images](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309673.aspx#bkmk_preandpost)